# How to put extra condition in select clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query: for each `FacilityCode` I am getting `LastCompletedOn` and `LastEDAOn`.

```
SELECT  Code ,
        MAX(DATEADD(HOUR, Seed_TimeZone.DifferenceFromUTC, CompletedOn)) 'LastCompletedOn' ,
        MAX(DATEADD(HOUR, Seed_TimeZone.DifferenceFromUTC,LastUpdateDemographicsDate)) 'LastEDAOn'
FROM    PatientCharts WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN Facilities WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Facilities.FacilityId = PatientCharts.FacilityId
        INNER JOIN Seed_TimeZone WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Seed_TimeZone.TimeZoneId =      Facilities.TimeZoneId

WHERE   Facilities.IsActive = 1
        AND PatientCharts.IsDeleted = 0
        AND PatientCharts.IsErroneous = 0
        --AND dbo.PatientCharts.ChartStatusID=1
GROUP BY Code
```

I want to put the commented condition "AND dbo.PatientCharts.ChartStatusID=1 " on `LastCompletedOn`. I have tried putting the whole query as a subquery but the same value is repeated for each facilitycode. How to accomplish this.

**ANSWER**

Response suggested by srgerg works fine. However we can get the same result by using a extra join

```
SELECT  Code ,       
        MAX(DATEADD(HOUR, DifferenceFromUTC, compOn.CompletedOn)) 'LastCompletedOn' ,
        MAX(DATEADD(HOUR, DifferenceFromUTC,Prim.LastUpdateDemographicsDate)) 'LastEDAOn'
FROM    PatientCharts AS Prim WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN Facilities WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Facilities.FacilityId = Prim.FacilityId
        INNER JOIN Seed_TimeZone LEO WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON LEO.TimeZoneId = 
  Facilities.TimeZoneId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientCharts compOn ON compOn.PatientChartId = prim.PatientChartId AND compOn.ChartStatusID=1      
WHERE   Facilities.IsActive = 1
        AND Prim.IsDeleted = 0
        AND Prim.IsErroneous = 0        
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: You cannot "put a condition" onto a specific field - only on the entire SELECT statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT  Code ,
        MAX(CASE PatientCharts.ChartStatusID
            WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(HOUR, Seed_TimeZone.DifferenceFromUTC, CompletedOn)
            ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, '1-Jan-1900') END) 'LastCompletedOn' ,
        MAX(DATEADD(HOUR, Seed_TimeZone.DifferenceFromUTC,LastUpdateDemographicsDate)) 'LastEDAOn'
FROM    PatientCharts WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN Facilities WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Facilities.FacilityId = PatientCharts.FacilityId
        INNER JOIN Seed_TimeZone WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Seed_TimeZone.TimeZoneId = Facilities.TimeZoneId
WHERE   Facilities.IsActive = 1
        AND PatientCharts.IsDeleted = 0
        AND PatientCharts.IsErroneous = 0
        --AND dbo.PatientCharts.ChartStatusID=1
GROUP BY Code
```